# thread exit discrepency in multi-thread scenario

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, printf

I have written a very simple code for practicing semaphore. Task is to sell tickets and each thread should update the shared variable of total tickets till it becomes zero. Issue I am observing is - the thread which sells last ticket and makes ticket_count = 0 by decrementing it exits without printing how many total tickets it sold. I added mutex around printf just for hack of it as I read about issues of printf in multi-threaded environment on SO. Reason I find this issue different than normal printf issues pointed at SO with regard to multi-threading is - its always ( not always 8/10 times - issue is intermittent - other 2 times it prints all 4 threads ticket sold) the last thread i.e. the one which sells last ticket skips the printf and exits. Can someone point me what am I doing wrong ?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUMTHREADS  4       /* number of threads i.e. ticket sellers */

static unsigned int ticket_count = 25;

pthread_mutex_t mutex2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

sem_t mutex;

void *ticketProcessing(void *arg)
{
    bool loop_alive = true;
    int local_counter = 0;
    while(loop_alive)
    {
        sleep(1);
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        if (ticket_count > 0)
        {
            local_counter++;
            ticket_count--;
            printf(" thread id -- %d - decided to sell 1 ticket \n ", (int)pthread_self());
        }
        else
        {
            loop_alive = false;
        }
        sem_post(&mutex);
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);
    printf(" ticket sold by thread id -- %d -- is  %d \n ", (int)pthread_self(), local_counter);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);
  //  return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t sellingTicket;
    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < NUMTHREADS; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&sellingTicket, NULL, ticketProcessing, NULL);
    }

    i = 0;
    while(i < NUMTHREADS)
    {
        pthread_join(sellingTicket, NULL);
        i++;
    }


    printf(" All threads exited !!! \n ");
    return 0;
}
```

Edit : I tried to create array and join in below fashion and it works

```
 pthread_t threads[4];

 for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
 {
     pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, ticketProcessing, NULL);
 }

for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
}
```

Comment: Your main thread wait synchronisation is incorrect. So its not waiting properly for all threads to exit before exiting the main thread (which also stops all the child threads). `pthread_join(sellingTicket, NULL)`. That waits for the *same* thread on each loop - the last thread to be created. You need a *seperate* `sellingTicket` pthread_t variable for each child thread.

Comment: @kaylum - I see point you are making but unable to implement - pthread_join such that it catches all the created thread, can you please give an example in my scenario - way I have created threads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your join loop tries to join the last thread over and over rather than trying to join each thread that was created. You need to keep track of the thread IDs so that you can join them all.

Once you've joined a thread, the thread ID is invalid and it is a serious mistake to pass it to any pthread_* function.

Comment: Sorry but I am still not able to understand and surprisingly I am not finding example to join multiple threads way I have created. Could you please add that with your answer ? Also the while loop I kept near pthread_join was during additional debugging ..if I remove the while loop near pthread_join and just keep pthread_join(sellingTicket, NULL); I see no impact on result

Comment: '@thedreamer if you wish to join all the threads, you shoud make 'sellingTicket' an array.  Just look at your code again - the pthread_create() loop is overwriting the same 'sellingTicket' var each time round, so losing all the thread references except the last:(

Comment: @MartinJames : Thank you for the pointer, yes I did that eventually as updated in the edit section and things worked fine. Question - why would I get 4 different thread id's if there was overwriting happening and returning of 3 threads ( hmm ..atleast printf showed 3 different thread id) exited and not just 1 ? Can you please help me understand it

Comment: @thedreamer The threads each had their own ID, you just didn't keep track of them correctly.